# Query result in codeigniter save in session display different results when used in controller functions using var_dump

Tags: codeigniter

I have used a CodeIgniter session to save result from database query in my model, for the first time I have  used var_dump function to view the result save in the session variable and it's all okay but as I used thesame session to display the result to other function in my controller it only display the last row of the result not all the results that were originally save in the session.

```
**Students Controller**

function get_student(some parameters)
{
$print_result=  $this->course_booking_model->get_student_ajax($config["per_page"],$page,$result,$tennant_id,$sort_by,$sort_order);
$this->session->set_userdata('print_result',$print_result);
$data['data_student'] = $this->session->userdata('print_result');
var_dump($this->session->userdata('print_result'));
}
```

Another function within thesame controller

```
function export_students()
{
$data['data_print']=$this->session->userdata('print_result');
$this->load->view('view_students_pdf',$data);
var_dump($this->session->userdata('print_result'));
}
```

The var_dump function will have different outputs

Comment: can you show us your models function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

Controller function 1:

```
$query = $this->course_booking_model->get_student_ajax($config["per_page"],$page,$result,$tennant_id,$sort_by,$sort_order);
  $new_data=array(
   'pdf_data' => $query
  );

  $this->session->set_userdata($new_data);
  var_dump($this->session->userdata('pdf_data'));
```

Controller Function 2:

```
$data=$this->data;
$tennant_code=$this->session->userdata('username'); 
$query=$this->session->userdata('pdf_data');
var_dump($query);
```

Comment: Can you explain what the issue was and how your code resolves it?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$this->session->set_userdata('print_result','value')` you are **setting** the value of the variable just as if you were calling `$print_result = 'value';`, that means that the previous value will always be overwritten. If you wish to keep appending values to a session data variable I suggest you use an array as the value, you just will have to retrieve the current data and append a new element to the array each time you wish to update the value. Something like:

**First value**

```
$this->session->set_userdata('print_result',array($print_result));
```

**Append new value**

```
$this->session->set_userdata('print_result',array_push($this->session->userdata('print_result'),$new_result));
```